# C: Easy and fast hash table for chess?

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, chess

I was wondering if anyone knows of a good implementation of a hash table in C. All I'm trying to do is hash a chess board. I just want the implementation to be quick and with the ability to clear the table in one go. Any help would be appreicated!

Comment: Hello John, and welcome to the site. Please, take a look at the ['how to ask'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to have a better idea of how to ask good questions (then augmenting the chance of getting good answers) on stackoverflow. Your question at the moment is too broad and does not show any research effort nor examples.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but there's no need to hash a chess board. Just use indices of `8*file + rank`, where `file` and `rank` have C-style indices from 0 to 7. Hashes are useful if your index or key can be any data that can't be mapped to small integers easily. (You can, of course, consider the indexing via file and rank a minimal perfect hash with 64 keys.)

Comment: @John, you need to be careful here. Hash table is a very common data-structure in all engine, but it exists for a very different purpose. Another name is transposition table. Please google for details. Your terminology here for chess is misleading.

Comment: Also, "hash a chess board" is reserved for hashing with zobrist keys in chess programming. A better phase that really reflect what you're asking is: "hash chess board coordinates".

Answer (score 0):

In chess, it is mostly called "transposition table". It is a more specialized data structure than a hash table.

Transposition tables are more like caches. They are faster than classical hash tables because their collision handling is much simpler. Old entries get evicted, eventually. In contrast, a classical hash table must never delete entries unless it is requested.

I am not aware that there is a reusable implementation of transposition tables. All chess engine that I have seen, bring their own implementation. It consists of two aspects:

- The transposition table itself
- A hash function `hash` that maps the position to a key (for more details, take a look at [Zobrist hashing](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Zobrist+Hashing))

The transposition table itself can be very easy. As a start, you can simply use one big array:

```
Entry* table = malloc(n * sizeof(Entry));
// ...

// clear transposition table
memset(table, 0, n * sizeof(Entry));

Position position; // the chess position
// ...

Key key = hash(position);

// probe
Entry entry = table[hash(position) % n];
if(entry.key == key)
{
  // found something --> entry can be used
  ...
}

// store
table[hash(position) % n] = updated_entry;
```

More advanced transposition tables often use multiple slots, so entries from deeper searches are no evicted by entries from lesser searches. Preventing data races in multithreaded engines also makes actual implementation more tricky.

Here are some further links that should help you to write your own:

- http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Transposition+Table
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_table